# Laravel Invalid argument supplied for foreach() problem

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get a list of things from the Steam service on the main page of the site. But I get an error: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`.

My blade:

```
            @foreach(json_decode($giveaway->items) as $item)
            <img class="giveaway-item-img" src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/570/{{$item->classid}}">
            </div>

        <div class="giveaway-item-name">{{$item->name}}</div>
        @endforeach
```

And my Controller:

```
    #GiveAway
    $kolvo=\DB::table('giveaway_items')->where('status',0)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->count();
    $giveaway = Giveaway::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
    $giveaway_users = \DB::table('giveaway_users')
        ->where('giveaway_id', $giveaway->id)
        ->join('users', 'giveaway_users.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->get();

    $game = Game::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
    $items = PagesController::sortByChance(json_decode(json_encode($this->_getInfoOfGame($game))));
```

But every time i got error. What could be the problem, how to fix the error?

Comment: can u post the `dd(json_decode($giveaway->items))`

Comment: string(22) "Crimson Wyvern Bracers"

Comment: so it not array. it just string..., you cannot foreach string.

Comment: oh, ookay. i will go and try to make a json

Comment: try to debug from here `PagesController::sortByChance(json_decode(json_encode($this->_getInfoOfGame($game))));`, dont make assumptions that json_decode, or encode have a valid data sent, for the `$this->_getInfoOfGame($game)`, you can set it's return value to something like `return $data?:[];` so that should return the data if exists or an array (valid data for json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you're using this in your php:

```php
$items = PagesController::sortByChance(json_decode(json_encode($this->_getInfoOfGame($game))));
```

do you really need to use json_encode, then json_decode here?

- is `$this->_getInfoOfGame($game)` return array ?
- is `PageController::sortByChange()` returning array ?

I would suggest not to overuse json_encode, json_decode, keep them as arrays in your php codes, only json_decode Steam data (i assume you're taking data from steam);

- Send the data as array to your views (way easier to debug), it's up to how you wrote your code, but i personally don't see the use of json_decode(... in the views.

Let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 3):

Please Use this code

```
@foreach (json_decode($giveaway->items?:"{}") as $item)
```

I think the value of $giveaway->items is Null

Comment: var_dump give me result: string(22) "Crimson Wyvern Bracers" . but some of DB tables empty: created_at, updated_at

Comment: yes, now i see, that string. but don't know how to fix this and make normal json

Comment: Can you share the exact content in the $giveaway->items

Comment: it say only 1 item string(22) "Crimson Wyvern Bracers". And in DB listed only 1 item

Comment: You can't execute that for loop. You must store data like this {'classid':'your_classid', 'name':'name'}

Comment: If the data is not json, please hide that block

Answer (score 2):

By default, [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) will return an object. You need to provide `true` as the second argument to get an associative array.

```
@foreach(json_decode($giveaway->items, true) as $item)
```

Comment: nope, doesn't work.. all information i have in DB, i check it

Comment: Try debugging the information, are you sure `$giveaway->times` contains a valid json string?

Comment: var_dump give me result: string(22) "Crimson Wyvern Bracers"